# Hibernate Query Language: Getting a SQL Syntax Error for my Query

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, relational-database

I already checked many related questions but the answers there did not fix my problem yet.

I have entities `User` and `Character` that are mapped via Hibernate.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username" }))
public class User {
    @Id
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "character", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "charId" }))
public class Character {
    ...

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

I want to select all characters that have a specific username, so the query that I use looks like this:

```
private final static String RETRIEVE_CHARACTERS_FOR_USER = "select c from Character as c inner join User as u where u.username = :paramUsername";
```

and my Code looks like this:

```
result = session.createQuery(RETRIEVE_CHARACTERS_FOR_USER, Character.class)
                .setParameter(PARAM_USERNAME, user.getUsername()).getResultList();
```

I also tried to remove the foreign key, use `String username` instead of `User user` and just query for `c.username`, so I am not even sure if the problem is Hibernate related...

I hope you can help me! :)

Comment: Because I heard that such error can occur because one is using reserved keyowrds in an SQL query, I found this (https://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/) to check whether 'character' is a reserved keyword, it told me that in MySQL5.0 it is not. In my hibernate properties I have set my dialiect to MySQL5InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private final static String RETRIEVE_CHARACTERS_FOR_USER = "select c from Character c where c.user.username = :paramUsername";
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I keep getting the same error: ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character character0_ where character0_.username='test'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually it was really a problem with the 'character' keyword... changed the table name to 'charac' and it worked fine.